How to efficiently paginate large nested lists in DynamoDB?
I'm working on a chat application where each chat session is stored as an item in a DynamoDB table. The structure of a chat item looks like this:
{
  "chatId": {
    "S": "f1b96d1d-516f-4c45-8952-8e146b969763"
  },
  "interactions": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "message": {
            "S": "Yooooooo"
          },
          "response": {
            "S": "Dummy response for: Yooooooo"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "S": "2024-05-31T06:19:28.799Z"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "message": {
            "S": "Yooooooo New one"
          },
          "response": {
            "S": "Dummy response for: Yooooooo New one"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "S": "2024-05-31T06:20:01.837Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "userId": {
    "S": "a5054135-2fb2-4694-8a17-df8ecdcaab9b"
  }
}

If the chatId is provided in the request body, the application appends the new interaction (message and response) to the existing chat's interactions list. Otherwise, a new chat item is created.
Given that a single chat session could potentially contain thousands of interactions, I need to implement efficient pagination to retrieve these interactions without degrading performance.
Also want to know if is it possible to store a lot of interactions [n] in a single chatId interactions array.
I have tried searching online but found very less resources for the same.

Why are there multiple messages in one item? Why not have one message per item and then have the chat id as pk and the timestamp as sk!?

Unfortunately your falling into a common trap, I'll have a blog post out in the next couple of weeks defining how to store chat messaged in DynamoDB efficiently.
Your biggest problems here are

item size limit (400KB)
the cost to update an interaction, if the item is 300KB and a user simply says 'hi', it will cost 300WCU

A better approach is a denormalized data model:



PK
SK
Data




ChatId
ChatId
Metadata about the chat


ChatId
MessageId(ULID)
message 1


ChatId
MessageId(ULID)
message 2


ChatId
MessageId(ULID)
message 3



Now, still with a single request, you can get all the chat history back. However you'll never hit the 400KB limit and the cost of a new interaction can be as low as 1KB.
Essentially you use Query instead of GetItem and just pass the ChatId and you'll get the results in ascending order by default, or optionally descending (latest message first).

Just in case someone doesn't know, ULIDs are lexicographically sortable, and are a great fit for range keys in dynamodb. Great answer Leeroy

Thanks that was a great help changed the table structure now it works perfect.

Excellent. Feel free to accept the answer.
